# How to Lock Specific Column only when Paste?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how can I lock a specific column only when copy/paste in Worksheet Change and still make this specific column not locked when nothing is getting copy/pasted?

What I mean is, I want, for example, Lock a specific column when `cutcopymode = 1`
in change event, (I want to lock specific column only when copy/paste, because the column should not be locked if nothing is getting pasted) is this possible to do it? If it is, can someone provide some examples how to do this on vba?

Comment: So you want to lock specific Column after data pasted. Is it true?

Comment: Or you want to prevent users from pasting copied data to that column and force them to just type data manually?

Comment: When copied paste data i want to lock columns (less the first column) lets say column A should be unlocked and Column B locked ..... , when is not copy paste all columns should be unlocked.

Comment: So When I as a user copy data from a place and come to excel, column B should be locked before I do paste. Is it true?

Comment: @Hammed Yes, if user inted to paste/copy. But if dont paste/copy all column should stay unloncked.

Answer (score 0):

Try This and feedback:

In the VBA window, write following code in the Sheet1 code page:

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal TargetRNG As Range)
If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy OR Application.CutCopyMode = xlCut Then
    If Intersect(TargetRNG, Range("B:B")) Then
        Application.Undo
    end if
End If
```

End Sub